# Is it possible to create an email without a mobile phone number?

Tags: outlook.com, security, mobile, sms, verification

I tried signing up for a Hotmail account and thought that went fine. That is, until I tried sending an email. When I hit send, a small box comes up asking me to verify via SMS. I tried to google this and also set up a two step verification adding alternative email but this box stills comes up. So I can not send any mail, which refutes the purpose of making an account.

So, is this some sort of technical issue (considering I have verified through the two-step verification multiple times now), in fact each time I log into the account or is there a way to avoid having to verify by SMS?